# Sort by string length and associated pound

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a disturbing case : I would like to sort a list of strings with an associated weight, like that :

```
@array = [{0 => "string"}, {0 => "my string"}, {2 => "my very long string which I want to match"}]
```

The result of the sort should be:

```
{2 => "my very long string which I want to match"}
{0 => "my string"}
{0 => "string"}
```

The first element is the very long string because the difference pound/string.length has a better percentage as others.

I tried to sort by grouping by weight, and after by strings but it doesn't work. I also tried to calculate ratios, but I'm still not getting the right ordered list.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Hashes containing always one element is a typical data structure smell. Any justification?

Comment: I used hashes but I also can use other data structures. I compare strings with other and the pound is the difference between the "modified string" and the "real string"

Comment: I use Levenshtein algorithm to compare strings. It generates a score which reflects the difference between these strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@array.sort_by do |h| 
  pound, string = h.first
  -pound.to_f / string.length
end
#=> [{2=>"my very long string which I want to match"}, {0=>"my string"}, {0=>"string"}]
```